# Programmatic authenticatication using a session variable

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get authentication working in Symfony2.

My users use a login form somewhere else on the site that is not controlled by symfony2.

what I would like is Symfony to detect the users are already logged in and authenticated by reading a session variable and comparing against the DB.

I don't want to reimplement a login form on the symfony part of the website.

In symfony 1.x, for example, I would simply overload the BasicSecurityUser class and use the setAuthenticated method, but it seems this is not possible in Symfony2.

Is there any simple way of achieving the same result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you know the user name of the authenticated user, you can log them in with:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class MyController {

// Takes either userName or an actual user object
protected function setUser($userName)
{
    if (is_object($userName)) $user = $userName;
    else
    {
        $userProvider = $this->get('zayso_core.user.provider');
        // Need try/catch here
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($userName);
    }
    $providerKey = 'secured_area';
    $providerKey = $this->container->getParameter('zayso_area.provider.key'); // secured_area

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: From where should I call your method? the login method specified in security.yml ?

Comment: Yep.  That is probably the cleanest spot.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. It ends up in endless redirections between login and the page requested ...

Comment: Go ahead and add yourself a login form and use it to make sure you have the security system properly configured.  Just follow the examples in the manual.  Once you are certain that the security system is properly working as designed then replace the form with code above.  The security system can be a bit tricky.  I made my own simple bundle when I was learning it.

Comment: It was a matter of bad regular expression matching in the firewall rules indeed ! I had a catch all rule with `pattern: ^/` and a login firewall with `pattern: ^/login` and `anonymous: ~` what happened is `login_check` matched `^/login` as well. Solution was to replace the login pattern with `^/login$` to ensure `login_check` was still  inside my main firewall rule and didnt allow anonymous users ! Thank you for your help !